# Cross Reference of Environments

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, counters

I defined a personalized table environment as follows:

```
\newcounter{Table}[section]
\newenvironment{Table}[1][]{
\refstepcounter{Table}
\newcommand{\tbtitle}{#1}
\begin{center}
}
{
\vspace{0.3cm}\\\textbf{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\color{black!80!blue}Table \thesection.\theTable} \fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont\textit{\tbtitle}\par
\end{center}
}
```

When I do `Table \ref{table:1}`, suppose the label exists, I only get `Table 1`. How can I also include chapter and section numbers so I get `Table 3.1.1`, for example?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\theTable}{\thesection.\arabic{Table}}`, assuming that `\thesection` itself uses `\thechapter.\arabic{section}}`. `\refstepcounter` uses the `\the....` of the counter being refstepped to generate the label value. If your `\theTable` contains only the standard `\arabic{Table}` setup, the label will be written as `1` etc.

Comment: By the way: Fragments as your code above aren't really useful -- provide a compilable document, not pieces of code that has to be glued together to get a running example

Comment: Thanks for answering my question again, Chris! It was really helpful.

Comment: You will only be able to use this environment once without error, though, because the command `\tbtitle` will exist after the first creation. Also, you are inserting spaces which you probably don't want so don't be surprised if you get weird spacing issues. In any case, it would probably be better to use a dedicated series of `\caption`s for this kind of case so that you can, if you want, create a list of Tables or whatever. But whether you need that structure depends on the use, really, so it might be overkill.

Comment: @cfr: `\tbtitle` is being defined within the environment -- it's in a group and is undefined outside. Try `\meaning\tbtitle` after calling the environment.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer So it is. I get confused without indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working version, but I don't recommend this wrapper environment actually.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{Table}[section]


\renewcommand{\theTable}{\thesection.\arabic{Table}}

\newenvironment{Table}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{Table}
  \newcommand{\tbtitle}{#1}
  \begin{center}
  }{%
    \vspace{0.3cm}

    \textbf{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont\color{black!80!blue}Table \theTable} \fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont\textit{\tbtitle}\par
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\section{First}

\begin{Table}{Foo}
  My nice table
\end{Table}

\begin{Table}{Foobar}
  My other nice table
\end{Table}


\end{document}
```